# How do I enable my type for std::ranges::to?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

How can you convert to a custom data structure using `std::ranges::to`?

Basically something like

```
struct my_data {
   char b;
   int foo;
   std::string baz;
};

auto text = "v 3 fool|x 56 description|e 123 name"sv;

auto converted = text | std::views::split('|') 
               | std::views::transform([](auto r) { 
                   return r | std::ranges::to<my_data>();
               }) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
// converted should be a vector<my_data>
```

What kind of thing does `my_data` need to have to be able to convert to it using `std::ranges::to`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four possible constructors that `r | std::ranges::to<C>{}` will use.  In order of preference (and ignoring perfect forwarding for simplicity):

1. `C(r)` - pass the range object to the constructor.
2. `C(std::from_range, r)` - as above, but explicitly tagged
3. `C(std::ranges::begin(r), std::ranges::end(r))` - iterator/sentinel pair.
4. `C c; c.reserve(std::ranges::size(r)) /* if supported */; std::ranges::copy(r, std::back_inserter(c));` - default-construct then copy.

It's probably easiest to create a constructor of the first kind that accepts a range:

```
my_data(std::ranges::input_range auto r);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can provide a constructor for `my_data` that takes a range and requires that a `std::string` object can be constructed from that range, then uses the created `std::string` to construct a `std::istringstream` object to initialize each member:

```
struct my_data {
  char b;
  int foo;
  std::string baz;
  template<std::ranges::input_range R>
    requires std::constructible_from<std::string, std::from_range_t, R>
  my_data(R&& r) {
    std::string s(std::from_range, std::forward<R>(r));
    std::istringstream is(s);
    is >> b >> foo >> baz;
  }
};
```

Then you can slightly rewrite (simplify) the pipe as:

```
auto text = "v 3 fool|x 56 description|e 123 name"sv;

auto converted = text | std::views::split('|') 
                      | std::views::transform(std::ranges::to<my_data>())
                      | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qnMjnrTaf)

As Barry's answer demonstrates, since splitting `subrange`s models `contiguous_range` in your case, using `std::ispanstream` to extract the formatted data can be a more efficient option:

```
struct my_data {
  char b;
  int foo;
  std::string baz;
  my_data(std::span<const char> sp) {
    std::ispanstream is(sp);
    is >> b >> foo >> baz;
  }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e8naae3nr)

Comment: Would've hoped for a direct conversion without the extra string step, but this works. Thanks.

Comment: @Phoenix that's unrealistic. You'd need a reflection mechanism for that; the std version is not available. But there are adhoc 3rd party open-source libraries with lots of limitation on the input type.

Answer (score 3):

The inner call to `ranges::to` here isn't really what the point of `ranges::to` is:

```cpp
auto converted = text
               | std::views::split('|') 
               | std::views::transform([](auto r) { 
                   return r | std::ranges::to<my_data>(); // <== this one
               })
               | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

It's true that, on some level, you're taking a range of `char` and converting it into `my_data`. But like - `my_data` isn't any kind of range, so it's kind of weird from a design perspective. The name of that function can really be... anything. Indeed you could just spell it:

```cpp
auto converted = text
               | std::views::split('|') 
               | std::views::transform(stream_into<my_data>); // <== this one
               | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

Providing a:

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto stream_into = [](std::span<char const> s) -> T {
    T obj;
    std::ispanstream(s) >> obj;
    return obj;
};
```

And now you have a generic extracter, with a spelling that's more reflective of the actual operation being performed.

---

Either way, note that:

```cpp
views::transform([](auto r){ return r | std::ranges::to<my_data>(); })
```

can be spelled as:

```cpp
views::transform(std::ranges::to<my_data>())
```

This is the general property of range adaptor closure objects: `R | C` and `C(R)` are equivalent, so `[](auto r) { return r | c; }` has the same meaning as `c`.